# why blender crash after tray subD complex shape?

Tags: modeling

i have decent pc ryzen 9 3900x 32 gb and gtx 1660 super. now i modeling turntable and have some problem not just now but often when i worked on complex shape blender start work very slow or even crash...here is example of object

[image: looks simple but its complex object]

Comment: i dont go more then view 2 render 2 in subdivision but after that....

Comment: I do not understand the second part of the comment.

Comment: blender not responding :)

Comment: How many millions of vertices are you dealing with?

Comment: around 49000 not millions :)